# Using SystemVerilog mailbox type as module IO

Tags: system-verilog

Is it possible to pass around a mailbox types in SystemVerilog using normal module IO?  Most of the book examples of mailbox only show them being used inside of SystemVerilog classes.  For example, could I do the follow?  Is it legal?

```
module driver(
    output mailbox mb
);

    mailbox   mbx = new(2);

    initial begin
        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) begin
            #1 mbx.put(i);
            $display ("[%0t] Put #%0d,  size=%0d", 
               $time, i, mbx.num());
        end
   end
endmodule
```

```
module sink(
    input mailbox mb
);

    initial begin
        forever begin
          int idx;
          #2 mbx.get (idx);
          $display ("[%0t] Got item #%0d, size=%0d", 
            $time, idx, mbx.num());
        end
    end
endmodule
```

```
module top;
   mailbox mbx;
   source(mbx);
   sink(mbx);
endmodule
```

Comment: SystemVerilog adds a fourth port type, called a ref port. A ref port passes a hierarchical reference to a variable through a port. instead of passing the value of the variable. The name of the port becomes an alias to hierarchical reference Any references to that port name directly reference the actual source.

Comment: A reference to a variable of any type can be passed through a ref port. This includes all built-in variable types, structures, unions, enumerated types, and other user-defined types. To pass a reference to a variable through a port, the port direction is declared as ref, instead of an input, output, or inout. The type of a ref port must be the same type as the variable connected to the port.

Comment: module decoder(
        ref logic [23:0] LUT [0:(2**20)-1] 
);

Comment: Passing variables through ports by reference creates shared variables, which do not behave like hardware.

Passing a reference to a variable to another module makes it possible for more than one module to write to the same variable. This effectively defines a single variable that can be shared by multiple modules. That is, procedural blocks in more than one module could potentially write values into the same variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but your code has many errors. You were mixing up `mb` and `mbx`, and your module `top` was incorrect. Also, I strongly recommend using a parameterized mailbox to make is strongly typed. You'll thank me later when using many mailboxes. The following works for me

```
typedef mailbox#(int) i_mailbox;
module source(
  output i_mailbox mbx
);

    initial begin
      mbx = new(2);
        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) begin
            #1 mbx.put(i);
            $display ("[%0t] Put #%0d,  size=%0d", 
               $time, i, mbx.num());
        end
      #100 $finish;
   end
endmodule
module sink(
    input i_mailbox mbx
);

    initial begin
        forever begin
          int idx;
          #2 mbx.get (idx);
          $display ("[%0t] Got item #%0d, size=%0d", 
            $time, idx, mbx.num());
        end
    end
endmodule
module top;
   i_mailbox mbx;
   source so(mbx);
   sink si(mbx);
endmodule
```